# DrawerLayout DrawerLayout cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, drawerlayout

i'm trying to use DrawerLayout in my application, as a start i've download the sample from google developer website and it worked just fine 
then i downloaded sherlockActionBar and tried to again to create m DrawrLayout and it gave me the following error 
"**DrawerLayout cannot be resolved as a type** "
i checked my google sample to check what i've done wwrong and i found that the google sample also have the same error !!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have imported the DrawerLayout class properly.Check your import statement.It should be something like this.

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
```